# How do I connect a 24v air purifier to hvac?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, air-filter, air-quality

I have a MicroPure MX4 that the previous homeowner left behind new in the box.  This is a 24v unit and needs to be hardwired.  My question is can I connect the two wires to the terminal where the thermostat comes in? They read 24v.  I checked the R and C terminal for the 24v reading. OR should I connect to the blower connection?

Comment: Did the unit come with instructions? If so, what do they say?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Owner's manual](http://www.dustfree.com/pdf/21424600EF.pdf).

> **Hardwiring Requirements (24V and 230V Operation)**
>
> **For 24V models:** Connect black and white wires to a dedicated 40Va transformer.
> (Not Provided.)

Notice that it says "*to a **dedicated** 40Va transformer*". This means that you'll have to install a 40VA transformer to power the device, not use the transformer in the HVAC unit.